# Unexpected behavior of Dropdown field when using of Slideup and Slidedown jQuery function on another field

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am getting an unexpected behavior on my dropdown input field when the Slideup jquery function works simultaneously. Requirement is that when user writes in the CustomerName text field, a message should appear above it and when user comes out of that field the message should disappear. Everything works fine but when I click on the dropdown box to select a state, I am getting a gap between the dropdown field and the selectable List. How can I remove this gap?

HTML Code-

```
  <div class="alert alert-warning lbls" id="Warning-alert" hidden="hidden">
     If customer is an active , please contact your.
  </div>
    <div class="innercontainer">
        <div class='row marginbtm-10'>
            <div class='col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6'>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class='row'>
                        <div class='col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6'>
                            <label class="lbls mandatory-filed">Customer Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-6'>
                            <input id="txtCustomerNamer" type="text" data-ng-model="CustomerInfo.CustomerName" class="form-control" maxlength="60" placeholder="Customer Name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
                        <label class="lbls mandatory-filed">Zip Code</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
                        <input id="txtZipcode" type="text" data-ng-model="CustomerInfo.ZipCode" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code" maxlength="5" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='col-lg-5 col-sm-4 col-md-5'>
                        <label class="lbls mandatory-filed">State</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-8'>
                        <select id="ddlSitusStates" class="form-control dropdown" data-ng-model="CustomerInfo.SelectedSitusState" title="{{CustomerInfo.SelectedSitusState.SitusStateName}}"
                            data-ng-options="situsState.SitusStateName for situsState in SitusStates track by situsState.SitusStateId">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

jquery code-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#txtCustomerNamer").focusin(function () {
    $("#Warning-alert").slideDown(500);
   });
$("#txtCustomerNamer").focusout(function () {
    $("#Warning-alert").show().slideUp(200);
   });
});
```

Image with Slidedown function-
[image]

Image with Slideup function-
[image]

Comment: I only see the problem if I click in the name field and then click directly on the select. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, when I am clicking directly on Select then only I am having this issue.